VueJS will not render a component if named "none"
I have a very simple component that I've used in vue v2 for a long time. Recently I've been upgrading an application to vue v3 (with the help of the @vue/compat plugin) and this component no longer gets rendered by vue. It simply ignores it and renders the raw HTML into the template.
However, if I rename the component from None.vue to something like NoneTag.vue it works fine. Did none become a reserved word in Vuejs v3?
The component is used throughout my application like this:
<something v-if="false" />
<none v-else/>

The HTML output in the browser would literally be: <none></none>
// None.vue
<script>
export default {
    compatConfig: {MODE: 3}, // not important here
    props: {
        tag: {type: String, default: 'span'},
        label: {type: String, default: 'none'},
    },
}
</script>

<template>
    <component :is="tag" class="text-muted">{{ label }}</component>
</template>

Note, the use of <component> is not really relevant here, since I tested it without the dynamic component and it has the same effect.

seems so, <None> fixes the issue though...

Wow, I didn't think to try that, you're right, it works. However, I'll probably just rename the component to something like  since I don't like having to use mixed-case component names.

Seems <none> is special for Vue, at least it indeed doesn't work as expected.
Try
<None/>

which seems solves the problem.
